# Where i make projects in Android studio or in Simple Console window?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

(I m a beginner) people says best way learning programming is make project, Now my question is Where i make projects in Android studio or in Simple Console window? i want to be android developer help please where i start making projects in Console window or in Directly Android studio. sorry for my english.

Comment: You should create projects in android studio only and start learning with google codelab

Comment: `people says best way learning programming is make project` the people saying this should surely show/say where they're making their projects too

Answer (score 1):

Go through this [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio) of google and install Android Studio then click on create new project. Follow all the steps given and you are ready to start working on your new project.